# TIF, JPEG TAG Library with Delphi IDE

Tags: delphi, svn, tortoisesvn

I found that libary [CCR EXIF](https://code.google.com/p/ccr-exif/) for browing tags with DELPHI source code. 
THere a still updates on that lib and I want my Delphi IDE take care to get the latest update to my code based on that lib .... how to do ?

I use SVN and tortoise as a repository for my delphi code

Answer (score 2):

The Google Code page you link to has the answer. Click on the [Source](https://code.google.com/p/ccr-exif/source/checkout) tab there and checkout the latest source from the repo. The SVN repo is at:

```
http://ccr-exif.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```

You don't need your IDE to do this for you. Although it can, at least in modern versions, as described here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Checking_Out_a_Copy_of_a_Repository

So you can checkout from the IDE if you prefer, or you can use TortoiseSVN or indeed the command line.

Generally you'll want to do more than just check out third party code. You'll want to commit it into your repo. If you are using SVN then follow the advice for vendor libraries in the SVN red book.

Now, it is possible that you want to configure your project to always take the latest version of the library. This is also possible. Add it as an SVN external, taken at the HEAD revision. Then every time you update the project you'll get the head revision of the external. This would be considered bad practice as you lose control of what code appears in your program. You won't be able to manage release branches properly, and unexpected changes to the external might break your program. If you want to do this anyway, consult the red book to find out how to configure externals.